# ffmpeg setting up in wamp (in local) OR server

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wamp, wampserver

can anyone explain the procedure of installing ffmpeg in wamp.
I got an answer to my previous question on ffmpeg and wamp that we have to interface the ffmpeg ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/)) with wamp.

I need to have a step by step process of how to do this, as I am confused with the interfacing little bit

I also want to know what is a way to install this ffmpeg into the server, or the procedure to do before we do the encloding procedures

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps.

1. Download ffmpeg_new from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
4. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)

And enable "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini.

All the best.

Thanks,

Kanji

Comment: Use these dlls for php 5.4

http://x32.elijst.nl/ffmpeg6-php54-win32-vc9-all.zip
http://x32.elijst.nl/ffmpeg6-php54-win64-vc9-all.zip

Comment: can you share this dll files because this link is not working?

Comment: There are no php_ffmpeg.dll files in that link you have.

Answer (score 0):

make all the following steps mentioned above with http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-5.3-win32-all.zip
I use  php 5.3.5 (wamp 2.1 x32)